# gpiod - programmatically monitor asynchronously in C++

Tags: c++, libgpiod

I'm looking at using the gpiod interface on an embedded Linux device with a C++ framework. The issue is that I haven't come across an example of how to asynchronously monitor inputs using gpiod. Ideally it would be something like gpiomon but not blocking.

I've used [asio](https://think-async.com/Asio/) (specifically asio::async_read) with file descriptors (fd) to accomplish this but it looks incompatible with gpiod ([related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30458971/how-to-use-boostasio-with-linux-gpios)).

Further it looks like mixing file descriptors with gpiod is messy as the gpiod lines assign there own fd internally which is not exposed as far as I can see.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Regards,

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I'd like to avoid the boost version of Asio (https://think-async.com/Asio/AsioAndBoostAsio.html)

Comment: As you wish; you know better. :)

Comment: I am still looking for a proper solution to this exact problem. I 've concluded that a separate thread can do the polling for a specific line (pin) and report to the main thread when the needed event type is detected.

Comment: Probably the way to go. If the thread can call a lambda might be better again

Answer (score 1):

In addition to blocking reads and timed waits, `libgpiod` exposes the line request `fd` so you have the option of using that with whatever async polling mechanism suits your application.

In `libgpiod v2` that is via `gpiod::line_request::fd()` - ref `gpiodcxx/line-request.hpp` (included by `gpiod.hpp`).

For `libgpiod v1` it is via `gpiod::line::event_get_fd()` - ref `gpiod.hpp`.

The [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30458971/how-to-use-boostasio-with-linux-gpios) is referring to GPIO `sysfs` file descriptors, which is the old deprecated GPIO API.  `libgpiod` uses the newer character device API and the returned `fd`s are suitable for `poll()`ing.